# Postgres function with dblink

Tags: postgresql

Got a problem here with following function in postgresql function:

im getting following error :

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>   HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function savegamelog(text,text,integer,integer,bigint,bigint,bigint,integer,integer,integer,integer) line 15 at SQL statement

my function is as follows:

```
    DECLARE
    s text;
    pDatatime integer;
    pDataid bigint;
BEGIN
pDatatime = floor(extract(epoch from '["now()",]'::timestamp));

IF length(pTableName) > 0 THEN
    UPDATE  lastgamedata  SET data= pData::bytea, gameid= pGameid, balance= pBalance ,bet= pBet, win= pWin, betline= pBetline, lines=pLines, datatime= pDatatime WHERE uid= pUserid;
END IF;

UPDATE gamestatistic SET totalin =totalin+pBet , totalout =totalout+pWin  WHERE gameindex=pGameid;

SELECT dblink_connect('host=127.0.0.1
user=user
password=pass
dbname=dbname');

SELECT dblink_exec('UPDATE hall SET totalbetin = totalbetin+pBet , totalbetout =totalbetout+pWin WHERE id = (SELECT roomnumber FROM users WHERE uid = pUserid)');

INSERT INTO gamedata( sessionID, uid, gameID, key, balance, bet, win, betline, lines, datatime, type, denomination ) VALUES ( 0, pUserid, pGameid, 0, pBalance, pBet, pWin, pBetline, pLines, pDatatime, pType, pDenomination ) RETURNING dataid INTO pDataid;

INSERT INTO gamedata_storage ( dataid, data ) VALUES ( pDataid, pData::bytea );

return pDataid;
END;
```

i know the function is wrong, and i dont know how to fix it..
can anybody point me in the correct direction pls..

Comment: change `SELECT dblink_connect(...` to `perform dblink_connect(...` as error message says

Comment: thank you...how can i accept this as answer?

Comment: added an answer.

Comment: Just FYI the modern replacement for dblink is FDW.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: @ScottMarlowe there are uses for dblink other than connecting to remote databases, the main one being [autonomous transactions](http://blog.dalibo.com/2016/08/19/Autonoumous_transactions_support_in_PostgreSQL.html) where you would be connecting dblink to the same db you're already connected to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following the error message instructions, change

```
SELECT dblink_connect('host=127.0.0.1
user=user
password=pass
dbname=dbname');
```

to

```
PERFORM dblink_connect('host=127.0.0.1
user=user
password=pass
dbname=dbname');
```